# How do I prevent slow responses from database to leave connections open?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2, redbean

We use redbean orm, mysql, and php7.0 (apache2)

When Mysql is slow to respond with a query result, PHP waits forever. If the MYSQL server is up, but slow to respond, It doesnt time out, it keeps the connections open waiting patiently.

Apache2 then keeps sending more and more and more requests, until apache can no longer handle connections.

So how do we handle this? max execution time in php.ini? Create max execution times for our DB ORM (RedBean PHP), or?

I am looking for a solution that doesnt create a bunch of stress and strain on the server.

Comment: hardware is cheap, buy more

Comment: Yeah - im spending 3k a month right now on servers that have 15% load; but 1 bad query and they all go south.

More hardware doesnt fix that. 20k; 50k; etc. Eventually they will all tip.